# Hive command line CLI history

Tags: hive

I am not seeing any history file - or being able to retrieve any history from past CLI Sessions at the command prompt.

Is there a setting to enable this?

Answer (score 5):

By default - Hive saves the last 100,00 lines of commands lines into a file $HOME/.hivehistory
source: [Programming in hiv](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023555.do)e -> chapter 2 : getting started -> command history

For me .hivehistory is available. hope this helps

Comment: Sure - and that is not happening according to the OP.

Comment: Directory permissions?

I'm more interested in how to disable it -- it leaks passwords into the history file!

Comment: For me it works, but it's fixed at the last 500 commands with no way to change it.

Answer (score 3):

type on the terminal "cat .hivehistory"

not able to see then

First check your location by "pwd"
if you are in home check with ls -a
if you are not able to see go to desktop path and you can type on the terminal "cat .hivehistory"

Answer (score 0):

Log in to the terminal type "cat .beeline".

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
 cat .beeline/history
```